# Difference between simple object literal and nested object literal

Tags: javascript, object, literals

Simple Object Literal:

```
var obj = {};
obj.name = 'stackoverflow';
obj.age = 13;
```

vs

Nested Object Literal:

```
var obj = {
  name: 'stackoverflow',
  age: 13
}
```

What is the difference between Simple Object Literal and Nested Object Literal?

Which way is better?

Comment: ...there is no difference. They are exactly the same, sans the fact that in the first one you define an object and add properties later, with the latter you define object with properties in one. There is nothing _nested_ there, either. Neither is "better" since that descriptor is meaningless without specifying better for _what_.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: @baao people will have opinions on two pieces of code that produce literally the same result?

Comment: @vlaz opinion based seemed to be the best close reason, no? :-)

Comment: i prefer the second one over the first, because the second is better readable - and put it in a direct context, as the first one tend to disperse over the code.

Comment: @baao I flagged it as "Unclear what you're asking". But to be honest, I'm not even sure how to flag "This question makes very little sense".

Comment: @@vlaz 
@@baao
@@NinaScholz
Sorry for asking the wrong question
I thought I heard it from somewhere, and so be it, I wanted to clarify my confusion.
Thank you for all of your opinion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are technically the same thing the difference is just in the syntax. You can create your object and all of it's properties at the same time, add the properties latter, or include some at creation time and then add others latter. It it's the flexibility of JavaScript objects.

One powerful aspect of this is that you can create an object in your program and then allow your users or application flow to add or remove the properties in dynamically latter through functions.